# The "only...but" problem

Tags: meaning, word-choice, connotation

In an effort to clarify my quandary, is it appropriate to use this statement to give condolence:

> I know you were only trying to help.

Or, does *only* imply that *you did more harm than good*? It feels like it does.

My confusion is that the statement,

> I was only trying to help.

does not imply that *I was only trying to help, but I admit that I caused harm*.

Comment: “Nothing someone says before the word *but* really counts.” –Benjen Stark to Tyrion Lannister

Comment: The use of "only" (trying to help) implies that there was some outcome other than help.

Comment: I'm only trying to answer this question, but it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: I edited, hopefully, for clarity. I'd really like it not to be closed because I think it is a usage question on the word "only".

Comment: I but point out that OP's example is only one way of using these words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I was only..." implies that the outcome went beyond, or differed from, the intent: "only trying to help," "only saying x and y," etc. The "but..." is implied because of that conditionality. The word "only" limits a statement to a specified context.

I think it goes a little further though: "but..." isn't inherently negative. The backhanded feel likely comes from the dissonance in the word "only." —"you were only trying to help" rarely means that the other party did *more* good than was intended. The word "only" reiterates and emphasizes the fact that the outcome differed from the intent or expectation.

Comment: I disagree with *"**but...** isn't inherently negative"*. The negative implication is still there in, for example, *"I ran to help but..."*, where we know before we read any further that the outcome *will be negative*. Except in (relatively uncommon) contexts where the default association is overridden, *but* always implies something negative. It just so happens that *only* is often used in negative contexts too.

Comment: However, "I ran to help, but someone had gotten there first" is not—to me—inherently *negative*.

"But..." is a *reversal*, though: "something good, something good, **but** something bad" or "something bad, something bad, **but** something good."

Comment: Or indeed, *I ran to help, but he hadn't been hurt at all*. By "negative", I just meant whatever follows "but" in such constructions will always negate or obviate the need for whatever comes before it.

Answer (score 1):

***"Only"*** goes to motivation in those example sentences, not to outcome.

To say "I was *only* trying to help" can be restated as, "My intention was to help, not to cause (harm), (problems), (more work for you)"

That applies to the other example also: "I know you were only trying to help" means "I know your intention was to be helpful, not to cause (fill in the blank)"